# How can I get travel time data between two locations using Google Maps in my C# Windows application?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I can manually login to Google Maps, specify two addresses as either actual addresses or lat-long coordinates, and ask for directions. After I select Driving, Mass transit, or bicycle directions, I get the list of instructions and the estimated travel time for the default route.

I would like my C# application to do this. The start and end points would be given as strings, and I would also specify what kind of directions I want (driving, mass transit, etc). The output should be an estimate of how much time it would take (according to Google).

I am trying to do this on a desktop C#/.NET app under Windows, not on Android.

Comment: @user1263981 Regrettably, no.

Answer (score 0):

Try [google.maps.DirectionsServiceClass](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#DirectionsService)